# Why is it so easy for people who lived in the KSA to get US visa?

Tags: united-states, saudi-arabia

I personally know many people who lived in the Saudi Arabia and achieved US visa very easily. For instance, if a guy from a country 'X' applies for a US visa, he gets denied. But, if the same guy lives in  KSA for some years, and applies from KSA, he gets the visa.

Why is it so easy for people who lived in the KSA to get US visa?

Is it because of Saudi policing/intelligence gathering system, or because of KSA's alliance with the USA?

Comment: This claim seems very vulnerable to selection bias since your only source is yourself, so you may need some verifiable source that actually shows it's really easy. [Saudi Arabia's refusal rate does seem low at 5%](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY17.pdf), so there may be something going on since, as an example, presumably-safe Denmark and Portugal are at 13% and 11%.

Comment: @Giter most people applying for a visa in Portugal would only do so if they're ineligible for the VWP for some reason. Its therefore not a valid comparison.

Comment: @JonathanReez: You're right, that could be messing up the numbers since (I assume) the three-month visas from the VWP are easier to get than the year-long ones. However, Austria and Malta are VWP countries at 5%, and Brunei is a VWP country at 3.7%, so who knows.

Comment: Since there's some doubt, a better Q. might be *"Is it easier for KSA residents to obtain US visas?"*, or perhaps *"US visa application refusal rates, ranked by country of origin?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main answer possibly has very little to do with security, and a lot to do with

1. The patterns of people applying for visas. As comments noted, some countries have a number of people who go via VWP (Visa Waiver Program)[https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html] instead of applying for visas, meaning the rest of the applicants aren't a representative pool
2. The main reason INS (DHS) refuses B* visas - the concern that the person will overstay the visa and stay in the country illegally.

   They basically assess the likelihood that someone will return, by using data points such as: are they married (if so, they are likely to return to their spouse), do they have other reasons to return (good job etc...).

   Now, if you compare Denmark (as per comment) at [2.2 marriage rate<sup>[1]</sup>](https://www.thelocal.dk/20150115/a-portrait-of-modern-denmark-in-ten-stats) and KSA (4.1), I strongly suspect that a far larger % of visa applicants from KSA will be married; which means they pass the INS's "likely to not overstay visa because there are reasons to come back" filter.

   <sub>[1] marriage rate = [crude marriage rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divorce_demography#Divorce_statistics_by_country) - crude divorce rate (per 1000 population)</sub>